# regular expression to find a specific letter into a link

Tags: python, regex

I have some links like these:

```
https://www.site.comf/floyda1bentley.html
https://www.site.coma/aarondoh.html
https://www.site.comp/pinkfloyd.html
```

I have to remove the letter after ".com" . but I'm a really noob with regex, and I don't even understand similar questions to apply them to my case. I understood (maybe) that lookaround have to be used..

thank you in advice

Comment: You can replace the character(s) matched by `(?<=\.com).+(?=/)` (if there is a match) with an empty string. `(?<=\.com)`, a *positive lookbehind*, requires the match to be preceded by `.com`. `(?=/)`, a *positive lookahead*, requires the match to be followed by `/`.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0u6cNK/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of links, you can use `re.sub()` in a list comprehension:

```
[re.sub(r'\.com[a-z]', '.com', l) for l in links]
```

Yields:

```
https://www.example.com/floyda1bentley.html
https://www.example.com/aarondoh.html
https://www.example.com/pinkfloyd.html
```